# How to add location into bash_profile

Tags: bash, ubuntu, directory, location

I have installed a program called RepeatMasker in Ubuntu but then when I run an installer called Maker the system mentioned that RepeatMasker is not installed.

```
 Checking external program dependencies...
 requires:
 !  RepeatMasker is not installed
```

The possible solution is that to add location of RepeatMasker into Maker.

```
Add the location where you installed RepeatMasker to your PATH variable in
.bash_profile (i.e. export PATH="/usr/local/RepeatMasker:$PATH").
```

How can I find my bash_profile in terminal and add the location of RepeatMasker to Maker?

This is my folder directories:

```
/usr/local/bin/maker
/usr/local/bin/RepeatMasker
```

Comment: Can you use the "which" command on it?

Comment: You have `/usr/local/RepeatMasker` and `/usr/local/bin/RepeatMasker` above ??

Answer (score 0):

run this command in terminal :

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/RepeatMasker:$PATH"' >>~/.bash_profile
```

to commit your changes run this command :

```
source .bash_profile
```

Comment: terminal return bash: ./bash_profile: No such file or directory

Comment: try this :- 
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/RepeatMasker:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc && source .bashrc

Comment: terminal return bash: .bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: try run previous commands  with any file of :-
/root/.bashrc -
/root/.profile - 
~/.profile - 
/etc/profile
-  /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: I tried this sudo echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin/RepeatMasker:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc && source /root/.bashrc   The terminal return permission denied

Comment: sudo echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin/RepeatMasker:$PATH"' >>~/.bashrc && sudo source .bashrc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110785/discussion-between-ahmed-farag-mostafa-and-xiong89).

Answer (score 0):

First, put the location of the third party application *after* the default path.  Unless you are sure you need to otherwise, you don't want someone with access to that path to put a `ls` command there to replace the default one.  Since you seem to be doing this for root you should be aware it's a poor security practice to do that.

I'd advise editing, instead of appending to the .bash_profile for sanity sake later.  Use vi/vim or any of the other editors.  You are going to use ~root instead of ~ b/c the ~ will expand prior to the command being ran as root.

`sudo vi ~root/.bash_profile`

`REPEAT_MASKER=/usr/local/RepeatMasker
PATH=$PATH:$REPEAT_MASKER`

For a single missing command, you can also use an alias, instead of adding the whole directory to your path.  If you need it for shell scripts, however, then man bash and look for expand_aliases for more information.

`vi ~root/.bashrc`

`alias RepeatMasker='/usr/local/bin/RepeatMasker'`

In the above entry, RepeatMasker is the executable, not the directory.  Your post uses two paths in it, so I'm confused as to which is right.  After any changes, source the files or relogin to see their effects.